# Design a Voltage controlled current source

Tags: current, source

[image]I have to create a current source (cs) capable of delivering up to 1.5 amps in order to calibrate a IC. The cs must be adjustable through a signal generator.

I thought I could use an op-amp and I have found some from TI (e.g. OPA548 from TI) but it works as a voltage source, which is a mistake and does not function properly.

I have not done anything similar and need some help. The input signal which is supposed to adjust the output is a sinusoidal waveform of 50Hz and IC must not see a signal higher than 500mV.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: If I were you, I would Google current source circuits, learn how they work, then see how you can adjust it to your needs

Comment: Summary - you need an sinusoidal voltage controlled current source capable of 50 Hz with peaks up to +/- 2.12 amps but limited to voltage output levels within +/- 500 mV?

Comment: +- 1,2-1,5A @andy aka and input at +-0,5V

Comment: What is the required output compliance (or to put it another way, what is the maximum load resistance for 1.5A).

Comment: Look for [Howland Current Source](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf)

Comment: What you need is probably an [OTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transconductance_amplifier) (Operational Transconductance Amplifier). You can make a fixed 1.5A high side current source and a variable low side 2.8A, controlled by the voltage. But the 0.5V requirement is a bit shady... Current sources are high impedance and principally make the voltage as high as needed to get the current they want to flow. So you'd need provisions to prevent voltages to rise above that value.

Comment: Hi again-
Spehro Pefhany the current source must be able to see a ferrite with 100 mOhm DC resitance and a very precise resistor of 150 mOhm
@Neil_UK I also implemented a solution with the OPA548 from TI but i need very precise resistors and also the ic is installed on a board manually without a heatsink. The prototype is supposed to be able to deliver up to 1A but due to, i want to believe, not accurate resistors it could provide up to only 200 mA which is not what i would like-
HarryH If we forget the 0,5 V could you please explain me exactly what do you mean?Do not forget Iout_max>1A